# Why is my browser downloads an index.html instead of to show it?

Tags: angularjs, nginx

I'm trying to set up a **Nginx** web server for serving a SPA based on **AngularJS** with single entry point at `index.html` file.

#### Here is my configuration:

```
server {
    server_name aislc.dev;
    root        /var/www/aislc/dist;

    # API backend
    location ~ ^/api/(.*)$ {
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        include        /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/aislc-api/index.php;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    types {
        text/cache-manifest appcache;
        application/json    js.map;
    }
}
```

When I try to open the site, the browser downloads a file with an unknown name and extension in which the contents of the `index.html

### Contents of `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link href="app.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Loading...</p>

    <script src="app.js" type="text/javascript" async></script>
</body>
</html>
```

#### Chrome screenshot

[image: chrome]

#### Firefox screenshot

[image: firefox]

## Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## I found the solution!

<del>I deleted the</del> `types` <del>section, because it is</del> directive replacing built-in mime types of nginx rather than extending them. Use `include` method:

```
    include mime.types;

    types {
            text/cache-manifest appcache;
            application/json    map;
    }
```